# Why my command is not working with nohup and SSH?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ssh, nohup

I'm restarting the server from my local mashine using the following command:

```sh
ssh -l root -p 22 $SERVER_HOST "cd $SERVER_DIR && nohup bin/restart &"
```

And it's not working, and prints nothing so I don't know what's the problem. But if I remove `nohup` and `&` - it's working. Why, and how to make it work (and continue in background after terminating ssh)?

Version without nohup works, but blocks the shell (it also prints output from the `bin/restart` script unlike the version with nohup). But I can't use it as I need the server to continue to work in background.

```sh
ssh -l root -p $SERVER_PORT $SERVER_HOST "cd $SERVER_DIR && bin/restart"
```

If that matter, the content of the `bin/restart` script (restarting Ruby on Rails app)

```sh
. /root/.asdf/asdf.sh
killall -r ruby
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails server
```

Comment: Don't start or restart services that way at all. Does your operating system use systemd? Then set them up as systemd services, and `systemctl restart your-service` will restart it (with the `--no-block` option if you want the command to return before the process has been successfully restarted). If your target OS is MacOS, its process supervisor launchd is controlled by launchctl much the same way.

Comment: Beyond that, `nohup` has no reason to exist -- everything it does bash can do only with built-in commands. The actions it takes are: (1) Redirecting stdin from `/dev/null` if it's currently coming from a TTY; (2) Redirecting stdout and stderr to `nohup.out` if they're currently going to a TTY; and (3) not propagating `HUP` signals (which bash doesn't do in the first place unless the shell is interactive, but which you can turn off even then with `disown -h`).

Comment: So if you use `exec </dev/null >some.log 2>&1; myprogram & disown -h $!`, congrats, you just manually did everything `nohup myprogram &` does.

Comment: Back to the question here: first place to start would be to read your `nohup.out` and [edit] in its contents.

Comment: Why can't you do `ssh -l root -p $SERVER_PORT $SERVER_HOST "cd $SERVER_DIR && bin/restart" &`?

Comment: @eewanco it works, but that way it won't release the shell, I have to press Ctrl+C to release it. Yes, I'm using it that way currently.

Comment: Replace `bin/restart` with `sleep 120` and examine the results.

Comment: Have you tried `ssh -t ...` ?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is:

```
ssh -tt -l root -p 22 $SERVER_HOST 'cd $SERVER_DIR && nohup bin/restart & sleep 1'
```

Tested with OpenSSH 7.2p2 (client & server), bash 4.3, Linux 4.15.

`-tt` forces ssh to allocate a terminal, which is apparently important for `nohup` to work.

`sleep 1` is not special, you just need something that will force the shell to context-switch, it could also be `/bin/true`, but that isn't as sure-fire.